# What is an FMB File? How can be open it?

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I used Notepad++,MS word,Adobe Reader so many tool but i am unable to open .FMB Extention file. could you Please help me?.

Thanks,

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2275885?tstart=0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.fmb is the extension of an Oracle Form.
It can only be opened using Oracle Developer Suite's Oracle Forms Builder.

Comment: You should be able to find these files in $AU_TOP

Answer (score 1):

It's the file extension used by Oracle Forms which is the IDE environment for Oracle applications.